# How to find the most duplicates in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm don't know how to find duplicates in an array. After finding the duplicates,

e.g. input: 3 5 7 7 7 7 7 12 12 12 18 20

/* program calculating
n * n * n * y = score

7 appears 5 times = 5*5*5*7 = 875

12 appears 3 times = 3*3*3*12 = 324
*/

output: 7 is the highest scoring duplicate at 875.

I am restricted to using only arrays, if/else, printf/scanf, loops..

My code so far (only works for some inputs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: `for(i = 0..{ for(i = 1` : use change other variable for inner for-loop.

Comment: you can sort the array, then run with one pass keeping track of the highest encounter yet, and the number itself.

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
//Provisional value
int hi_score = INT_MIN;//#include <limits.h>
int selectIndex = -1;

for(i = 0; i < nNumbers; i++){
    int dupCount = 0;
    if(selectIndex != -1 && array[selectIndex] == array[i])
        continue;//skip because It has already been calculated

    for(j = 0; j < nNumbers; j++){//Examine all because unsorted
        if((array[i] == array[j]))
            ++dupCount;
    }
    if(dupCount > 1){// need ?
        int score = dupCount * dupCount * dupCount * array[i];
        if(hi_score <= score){
            hi_score = score;
            selectIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
if(selectIndex != -1)
    printf("%d\n", array[selectIndex]);
```

Comment: You could start the `for (j =` loop with `for (j = i;` since you know that this number has not been seen before, so you don't need to rescan elements 0..i-1 — do you?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but case of include -10, -10, -10 : score 3*3*3*-10 < 2*2*2*-10 this is wrong score.

Comment: Hmmm...oh, yes.  You are only tracking one previously calculated value (the one with the current largest value), not all of them.  In which case, as you say, you do need to rescan the whole list, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

One way is a brute force algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 15

int calc_score(int number, int times)
{
    return times*times*times*number;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[MAX_NUMBERS] = { 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 12, 12, 12, 18, 20,13,13,14 };

    int n;
    int score;
    int scoreMax = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++)
    {
        int times = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUMBERS; j++) { if (a[i] == a[j])times++; }
        score = calc_score(a[i], times);
        if (score > scoreMax) {
            scoreMax = score;
            n = a[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%d is the highest scoring duplicate at %d\n", n, scoreMax);
    //7 is the highest scoring duplicate at 875
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Provisional value
int hi_score = INT_MIN;//#include

int selectIndex = -1;

for(i = 0; i < nNumbers; i++)
{

int dupCount = 0;//

```
if(selectIndex != -1 && array[selectIndex] == array[i])
    continue;//skip because It has already been calculated

for(j = 0; j < nNumbers; j++){//Examine all because unsorted
    if((array[i] == array[j]))
        ++dupCount;
}
```

if(dupCount > 1)
{

// need ?

int score = dupCount * dupCount * dupCount * array[i];

```
    if(hi_score <= score)
```

{

hi_score = score;

selectIndex = i;

}

}

}
if(selectIndex != -1)

```
printf("%d\n", array[selectIndex]);
```